# Pandas creating new column based on consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, shift

I have a Pandas dataframe like the one below, where column A is a series of strings, and values in column B are true/false depending on whether the value of column A is the same as the value of column A in the previous row.

```
A    B       
1    False          
1    True             
1b   False          
1b   True                
1b   True    
1    False
```

I want to add a new column, C, that assigns the same value (it can be any value) to all **consecutive duplicate** entries, but this value must be unique from the values assigned to other groups of consecutive duplicate entries. For example:

```
A    B        C
1    False    1       
1    True     1         
1b   False    2         
1b   True     2            
1b   True     2
1    False    3
```

Any thoughts about how to go about this in an efficient way?

Comment: I think `cumsum(!df["B"])` will get you very close

Comment: This worked, I changed column B to map False to 1, and True to 0. After that I ran df["C"] = df["B"].cumsum() to get the desired output. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-ngroup) + 1 be sure to `sort=False` to make sure groups are created in the order they appear in the DataFrame:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A', (~df['B']).cumsum()], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

```
    A      B  C
0   1  False  1
1   1   True  1
2  1b  False  2
3  1b   True  2
4  1b   True  2
5   1  False  3
```

---

Or either of the following can be used directly assuming values appear in sorted order with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum):

```
df['C'] = (~df['B']).cumsum()
```

```
    A      B  C
0   1  False  1
1   1   True  1
2  1b  False  2
3  1b   True  2
4  1b   True  2
5   1  False  3
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()
```

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Which would be the standard way to solve this problem if the `B` column was not already calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `shift` combine with `cumsum`

```
df['C'] = df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()
Out[191]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you are looking for.

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A').ngroup() + 1
```